# Flutter - video_player listener being called very slowly

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I want to get the current position of the video being played in real-time. I was thinking of using a listener, but if I do:

```dart
_controller.addListener(() => print(_controller.value.position.inMilliseconds))
```

It only prints the value every 500 milliseconds. This is too slow, the video is updating every 33ms or even more often. Anyone knows why is this happening and what's the proper way of achieving what I want?

P.S. I was able to achieve what I wanted by starting an AnimationController when the video starts, but this seems like a hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the delay is that `VideoPlayerController` is notifying listeners every 500 milliseconds. You can use a `Timer` to periodically get position of video player. Here is a sample code to do that

```
class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  VideoPlayerState createState() => VideoPlayerState();
}

class VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  Timer _timer;
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  void startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (Timer timer) async {
      print(await videoPlayerController.position);
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The position `videoPlayerController.value.position` is only being updated every 500 ms so that codes prints 5 times the same position and then prints a different one 500 ms ahead

Comment: My bad! I've updated the answer check it again. @JoãoAbrantes